# HTML subpage changes without change the url

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

I attempt to crawl reviews of this product using python, but I noticed that I change the page of the review page, the URL doesn't change at all, so I have no idea how to switch the pages of reviews in my program,
the URL I am trying to crawl is here: https://item.jd.com/7420374.html#comment

Comment: this really is not very clear at all - please clarify what you mean and share your code - trying to identify in your code where you think the issue might be

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium in headless mode to click on the review button, you can also use it instead of requests to get the html.